# Lighthouse Performance improvement for flutter [Scroll]

Tags: flutter, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

So I've build a static website using flutter (web-app) which is hosted on Firebase Hosting.

I checked my Lighthouse report using DevTools by chrome, and i get this diagnostic advice.
[image]

I did check for solutions but no hope.
I mean, is it something I could fix within flutter framework or am I missing something?